# Apply CSS between String Element

Tags: css, gantt-chart, frappe

I'm using [Gantt](https://frappe.io/gantt) component and i have lists of task in HTML, exaple:

```
Task 1: XXXX <b>YYYY</b> ZZZZZ

Task 1: AAAA <b>BBBB</b> CCCCC
```

My problems is YYYY and BBBB  have bold tag `<b>YYYY</b>`
Gantt not render bold tag and i see render: `XXXX ZZZZZ` output

it's possible create css class to specific the center string in bold ?

Comment: You could select the `b` tag in CSS or directly add a class on the b tag. You can check selector in CSS here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: May you try `<span style="font-weight: bold; color: red">YYYY</span>`? (I added red color so you see if there's a problem with font weight or the whole css)

Comment: @Shahriar not render HTML Tag